# search feature where we call the api when user presses enter or search bar or user stops typing in react native

Tags: react-native

I am implementing a feature in react native where i need to call the api once user has stopped typing or pressed enter or user presses serach option which appears at the bottommost coroner in android keyboard .
I understand that we need to use debounce and throttle in this part but how do we achieve all this in react native .
Any help would be highly appreciated be it demo or link .

Answer (score 0):

#### Example

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

const PizzaTranslator = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  return (
    <View style={{padding: 10}}>
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40}}
        placeholder="Type here to translate!"
        onChangeText={text => setText(text)} // Set the text on state
        defaultValue={text}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default PizzaTranslator;
```

As you can see in here, You can simply save the text change and when the user pressed enter, search option or whatever you want you can simply call the API with this state value.

For the `user has stopped typing` part. You need to handle yourself. If you want to detect it like after 1 sec, the user has stopped typing and then you can call the API. I guess TextInput does not have a feature for `stopped typing` one. You need to handle it on `onChangeText` prop.

*Example is taken from official react-native-dev doc.*